# CakePHP 3 - ForceIndex on MySQL

Tags: cakephp, indexing, orm, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

does anybody knows how it's possible to use the "force index" function on a mysql query in cakephp3 ORM?

i found some soloutions for cakephp2, but nothing for cakephp3. I know that's possible to make a raw query, but i prefer a way to use it with the cakephp orm.

thank you for your help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported out of the box. For a clean implementation you'd have to create custom/extened query and query compiler classes to add such functionality, something similar to `Query::modifiers()`.

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.3/src/Database/Query.php#L357**
**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.3/src/Database/QueryCompiler.php#L140**

The only other way I can think of, would be to slip it in via `Query::from()`, however this feels kinda akward, and more of a workaround.

```
$query = $Table->find();
$query->from($query->newExpr('table_name TableAlias FORCE INDEX (index_name)'), true);
```

A little more dynamic:

```
$table = $Table->table();
$alias = $Table->alias();

$query->from($query->newExpr($table . ' ' . $alias . ' FORCE INDEX (index_name)'), true);
```

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::from()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_from)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Raw Expressions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#raw-expressions)**